# Webby-Compass Integration - equivalent config.rb file?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, compass-sass, webby

In the [Compass screencast](http://wiki.github.com/chriseppstein/compass) at 23:08 Chris Eppstein starts editing a file called *config.rb*, in his pure Compass project.  Chris uses this file to configure relative path names in his images using the *img_url()* function (which must be undocumented as I can't find anything about it, in the [mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/compass-users/) or [on the website](http://wiki.github.com/chriseppstein/compass/).).

I'm working on a [Webby project](http://webby.rubyforge.org/) with [Compass Integration](http://wiki.github.com/chriseppstein/compass/webby-integration), and I can't find a *config.rb* file in my Webby project.  I'm guessing that the *SiteFile* file in the root directory of my project will do the same thing, but I'm not entirely certain about this.

Does anyone know what the equivalent to the *config.rb* file is in a Webby/Compass Integrated project?

Comment: Okay this one sounds like a question for the Webby mailing list.

Comment: I'm using Compass with Webby in http://github.com/burke/burkelibbey.org -- hopefully this helps. Corban's answer is correct, but it took me a little while to figure out how to make it play nice even after reading that on the wiki.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Screencast is most likely outdated.

To load compass into your Webby project, set up your Sitefile with the following options:

```
require 'compass'

Compass.configuration do |config|
  config.project_path = File.dirname(__FILE__)
  config.sass_dir = File.join('src', 'stylesheets' )
end

Webby.site.sass_options.update(Compass.sass_engine_options)
```

From https://github.com/Compass/compass/wiki/webby-integration